# RequireJs minifcation - complex directory structure

Tags: javascript, requirejs, minify

we have a problem at work, we are using require js but our folder structure is a bit different,
we have the following:

```
--js folder 
   --Folder
      ---some base js files
    -Folder 
       ---main
            --src
                ---require.js 
                --- require JS modules
         --plugin js files
         --more js files
```

We would like to minify all these JS files to a SINGLe js file for production as such

```
---js folder
    --min-all.js
```

Is this possible?
if so how? ..
Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

I just thought I would clarify that the other Folders contain standard non modular javascript files, they can be a mix of plugins or simple javascript helpers.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is: yes, RequireJS can do this.

Basically, you will need to create one JS file that requires all of the resources that you want minified. Then you will point the optimizer at that file and it will mash them all together.

```
require(["one", "../another/two", "folder/three", "folder/inner/four" ... ]);
```

If that file was called `myfile.js`, you would run the optimizer with similar parameters to this:

```
node r.js -o name=myfile out=optimized.js
```

If you have libraries or other files that you do not want included into the final optimized file, you would use the `excludeShallow` flag. e.g.

```
node r.js -o name=myfile out=optimized.js excludeShallow=jquery.min
```

There are more options so you should check out their [optimization documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) if you haven't yet.

Comment: So myfile.js would make all the includes, would it also need to include the files that are not under src/ ..? like the outside libraries, plugins, etc ?

Comment: IIRC the optimizer walks the dependency chain so making a "bootstrapper" like suggested here should bring it all in.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, in other workds, the file that is under data-main attribute  would become myfile.js?

Comment: If you want to include the external libraries in the optimized version, you would include them there. Otherwise, you will use the `excludeShallow` flag. Updating my answer momentarily...

Comment: No, not really. You dont need the `<script>` reference because you arent loading `myfile.js` on an HTML page. You are providing that file as an input to the optimizer. There is no HTML page involved when using the optimizer and hence there is no `<script data-main="...">` tag.

Comment: I had another questuin regarding the bootstrap, do we have to list every single js files?
We have a lot of them under other folders. 
Anything that is not under src/ is not using Require.js , they are simple javascript documents

Comment: As Aren mentioned, RequireJS will resolve all dependencies. So if you require 3 files, and those 3 files in turn require 50 other files and those 50 files require 100 others, all 153 files will be combined into the final output. So you dont need everything in the bootstrapper as long as they are somewhere in the dependency tree.

Comment: Thanks again Jeff, I was actually wondering about the non module js files that we have, they are not using modular approach

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21401/discussion-between-nima-and-jeff)